# What is this PCB (IC?) connector called?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit, connector

Can anybody tell me what this connector is called and how I could purchase one for my own prototype board?

This is a picture of a Nintendo Wii motherboard (bottom) and the bluetooth adapter (top).  I'd like to connect this bluetooth adapter to my own board for a project I'm working on so I need a connector like the one on the motherboard.

[image: Wii Bluetooth Adapter]

Here is another picture of both the board connector and module plug:

[image: Wii Bluetooth Module and Connector]

Thanks for any help!

Comment: looks like a custom DIP socket aka proprietary

Comment: share the pitch, height info

Comment: The connector is really, really small so I don't have anything to measure it.  If this is needed and you can't help without it, I understand and appreciate the help anyway!

Comment: unless measurement is done, part cannot be identified. if not identified, cannot be used in the project

Comment: Please photograph against a ruler for size reference avoiding perspective as much as possible. I would recommend investing in a vernier for measurements.

Answer (score 3):

It is very similar to the Hirose DF40 surface-mount "riser" connector. But I don't see any 16-pin versions. I wonder if that isn't a 20-pin version with the two end pins missing from each end?

Ref: https://www.hirose.com/product/en/download_file/key_name/DF40/category/Catalog/doc_file_id/31649/

Comment: I would ask over on EEVblog Forum

Answer (score 1):

If the quest is to find the connector type only, then it is very close to the **slimstack connectors** from Molex.

http://www.molex.com/molex/products/family?key=slimstack_fine_pitch_smt_board_to_board_connectors&channel=products&chanName=family&pageTitle=Introduction&parentKey=board_to_board_connectors

Images for reference: 16 pins are available. Unless p**itch and mated height** is known, a single part cannot be identified.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, although I know it's been a while. I've measured it and the exact part number is Molex 0541020164.

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0541020164/WM8876CT-ND/3197306

Answer (score 0):

I call them "board to board" connectors. Connector of this style have become very common in laptops, etc, and are made by all the usual connector companies in a variety of sizes and stacking heights.

You can search [Digi-Key.com](http://digikey.com) under the connector subcategory "**Rectangular - Board to Board Connectors - Arrays, Edge Type, Mezzanine**." You might be able to determine the manufacturer and model of those with enough detective work.

Answer (score -2):

https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0547220164/WM3446CT-ND/2405569

I think it's this one.  The matching part is down the page a bit.

Comment: This is the same product already suggested in the answer by Umar.  Posting repetitions of the same answer is generally discouraged here.

Comment: @Jules  I'm not sure if this is the same connector family that Umar had suggested.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - it definitely is: click on the link on Umar's post, select the 0.5mm pitch, and scroll down the list - the same part number is found in the 20-40 page of results.

Comment: @Jules  I've followed Umar's link.  The Molex family numbers at Umar's link were different.  [Unless I've missed something.]